# "API handler should not return a value, received object." Next JS 13.4 while sign in

Tags: session, oauth, next-auth, next.js13

- I am getting this error because i'm trying to sign in via github in nextJS

/app/api/register/route.ts

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";
import {NextApiResponse} from "next";
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: Request, res: NextResponse) {
  const body = await request.json();
  const {email, name, password} = body;

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

  const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email,
      name,
      hashedPassword,
    },
  });
  return user;
}
```

-I am following tutorial which is based on NextJS 13.2 maybe. so [...nextauth]
/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";
import {PrismaAdapter} from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import NextAuth, {AuthOptions} from "next-auth";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {label: "text", type: "text"},
        password: {label: "password", type: "password"},
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials?.email,
          },
        });

        if (!user || !user?.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }
        // return undefined;
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

/app/modal/RegisterModal.tsx

```
"use client";
import {AiFillGithub} from "react-icons/ai";
import axios from "axios";
import {FcGoogle} from "react-icons/fc";
import {useCallback, useState} from "react";
import {FieldValues, SubmitHandler, useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import useRegisterModal from "../hooks/useRegisterModal";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import Heading from "../components/Heading";
import {toast} from "react-hot-toast";
import {signIn} from "next-auth/react";
import Input from "../components/inputs/Input";
import Button from "../components/Button";

const RegisterModal = () => {
  const registerModal = useRegisterModal();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: {errors},
  } = useForm<FieldValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .post("/api/register", data)
      .then(() => {
        registerModal.onClose();
      })
      .catch((error) => toast.error("Some thing went wrong"))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  };

  const footerContent = (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 mt-3">
      <hr />
      <Button
        outline
        label="Continue with Google"
        icon={FcGoogle}
        onClick={() => {}}
      />
      <Button
        outline
        label="Continue with Github"
        icon={AiFillGithub}
        onClick={() => {
          signIn("github");
        }}
      />
      <div className=" justify-center text-neutral-500 text-center mt-4 font-light">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
          <div>Already have an Account?</div>
          <div
            onClick={registerModal.onClose}
            className="font-semibold text-neutral-800 cursor-pointer hover:underline"
          >
            Log in
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const bodyContent = (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <Heading title="Welcome to Airbnb" subtitle="Create an Account" />
      <Input
        id="email"
        label="Email"
        disabled={isLoading}
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
        required
      />
      <Input
        id="name"
        label="Name"
        disabled={isLoading}
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
        required
      />
      <Input
        id="password"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        disabled={isLoading}
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
        required
      />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <Modal
      disabled={isLoading}
      isOpen={registerModal.isOpen}
      title="Register"
      actionLabel="Continue"
      footer={footerContent}
      onClose={registerModal.onClose}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      body={bodyContent}
    />
  );
};
export default RegisterModal;
```

- here whenever i click on sign in with Github it will show callback url but won't give me the current user instead it shows

[next-auth][debug][PROFILE_DATA]

- where it shows my data

[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error getUserByAccount is not a function {
message: 'getUserByAccount is not a function',
stack: 'TypeError: getUserByAccount is not a function\n' +
'    at Object.callback (D:\Web Dev journey\NextJS\airbnb\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:83:39)\n' +
'    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n' +
'    at async AuthHandler (D:\Web Dev journey\NextJS\airbnb\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:208:28)\n' +
'    at async NextAuthApiHandler (D:\Web Dev journey\NextJS\airbnb\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:22:19)\n' +
'    at async NextAuth._args$ (D:\Web Dev journey\NextJS\airbnb\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:106:14)',
name: 'TypeError'
}
**API handler should not return a value, received object.**
[next-auth][debug][OAUTH_CALLBACK_RESPONSE]

- here it shows call back response as my data.
- I have tried returning various things but none of them worked

1. /app/api/register/route.ts

return NextResponse.json(user);
res.status(200).json(user);

return new Response(JSON.stringify(user), {
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
});

2. /pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

return undefined instead of user.

- so what could be the solution for this problem?